Why does an invariant measure define a Schwartzman cycle?
Let $M$ be a manifold with a flow $\phi_X:\mathbb{R}\times M\rightarrow M$ induced by a vector field $X\in \Gamma TM$.
Any Borel measure $\mu$ defines a $1$-current $c_\mu$, i.e. an element in the dual $(\Omega^1(M))^*$ of the space of differential $1$-forms on $M$, by
$$c_\mu(\alpha)=\int\limits_M \alpha(X) d\mu$$
for all $\alpha\in\Omega^1(M)$.
The differential $\partial$ on $1$-currents is defined as the adjoint of $d : \Omega^0(M)\rightarrow\Omega^1(M)$, i.e. $(\partial c)(\alpha) = c(d\alpha)$.
My question is about the following fact, which I have not seen proved anywhere:

The $1$-current induced by a $\phi_X$-invariant Borel measure $\mu$ satisfies $\partial c_\mu =0$ (i.e. is a Schwartzman cycle).

Clearly, for any $f\in C^\infty(M)=\Omega^0(M)$,$$\tag{1}\label{473873_1} (\partial c_\mu)(f)= c_\mu(d f) = \int\limits_M df(X)d\mu.$$
But why exactly does $\phi_X$-invariance of $\mu$ imply that this integral vanishes?
Update I think I can now show this in the case when $M$ is closed and the measure $d\mu$ can be expressed as a smooth differential form $\omega$: From \eqref{473873_1}, we get that (writing $L_X$ for the Lie derivative w.r.t. the vector field $X$)\begin{align}
(\partial c_\mu)(f) &= \int\limits_M df(X) d\mu\\
 &= \int\limits_M (L_X f) \omega\\
&= \int\limits_M L_X(f\omega) - f L_X\omega.
\end{align}
The first term should always vanish: $$L_X(f\omega)= \iota_X d(f\omega) + d\iota_X f\omega,$$
where $d(f\omega)=0$ since $\omega$ is a top-degree form and $$\int\limits_M d\iota_X f\omega = \int\limits_{\partial M} \iota_X f\omega = 0.$$
Thus,
$$(\partial c_\mu)(f) = -\int\limits_M f L_X\omega $$
for all $f\in\Omega^0(M)$, and so $\partial c_\mu=0$ if and only if $L_X\omega =0$.

Assuming $M$ is compact, the vanishing of that integral follows from Birkhoff ergodic theorem and the ergodic decomposition theorem. In fact, if $f\colon M\to\mathbb{R}$ and we write $\psi:=Xf$, for every ergodic $X$-invariant measure $\mu$ it holds
$$\frac{1}{T}(f(\Phi_X^T(x)) - f(x)) = \frac{1}{T}\int_0^T \psi(\Phi_X^s(x))ds \to \int_M\psi d\mu,$$
as $T\to+\infty$, and for $\mu$-a.e. $x\in M$. On the other hand, the left side of the equation tends clearly to $0$ as $T\to+\infty$ because $f$ is a bounded function (because we are assuming $M$ is compact).
By the ergodic decomposition theorem, this implies the integral vanishes for every $X$-invariant measure.
I'm not sure this holds without the compactness assumption.
